# Stream music from phone/computer via Raspi to AV-receiver DLNA

Tags: streaming

I guess there is a bunch of related topics out there but I am tired of searching, workarounds, solving problems and getting confused more and more. I want  to stream audio files on my computer or android phone to the raspberry pi which is connected by Hifiberry DAC to my old AV receiver.

At first I installed rpi-audio-receiver which did not work out. So, I installed gmediarenderer-ressurect which is now finally working - more or less. To cut things short:

- using Manajaro Linux on my station
- using LineageOS on my Android
- on the station GUPnP Universal Controller recognizes the Pi, VLC not, Kodi does but does not play music when choosing the raspi via context menu on music file
- on the phone UPnP Browser recognizes the Pi, BubbleUPnp and kodi do not
- I can play test sounds on my stereo, so the DAC is working

It seems to me that gmedia-renderer is not what I was looking for. Maybe you can point me to right direction. Thanks.

```
SysInfo
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
Debian 10.8
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17+ #1403 Mon Feb 22 11:26:13 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2
```

Regards
Stan

PS: I emphasize that I do not want to make files a/v to the raspi as e.g. visitors should be able to play music directly from their phones, too. Maybe I should just switch to bluetooth...

Comment: *"Maybe I should just switch to bluetooth.."* -> If you mean, get a bluetooth receiver for the AV receiver, yeah, much easier and cheaper than a pi.  The range tends to suck though, I've never seen one sold that didn't claim it was good to at least 10 meters but never found one that was reliable past 5.

Comment: If anyone wants to setup upnpdcli. Works with raspberrypi b+ above. https://diy-for-life.co.in/raspberrypi-music-streamer/upnp-renderer

Answer (score 0):

I am using my RPI 4 as network streamer (its USB output connects to my DAC) and that serves as:

1. squeezelight player (and LMS server) so I can receive my Tidal, Qobuz, Spotify music on it
2. DLNA receiver using minidlna so I can stream from any application from my computer/phone that supports DLNA (Audirvana, Squeezer)
3. Apple Airplay using shairport-sync
4. UPnP renderer using upmpdcli
5. MPD of course that is needed for minidlna

I am not sure if this helps you.
All the above are installed on vanilla Raspberry OS